# Wordpress - Show metabox on a specific page only

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

Developing a wordpress plugin where I create a page via the index.php file, this page also uses a custom template that required the user to edit information in a meta box.

I've added metaboxes before to plugins but never been in this situation - how can I specify the meta-box to only show on this one page?

Would be open to all suggestions - I'm sure it's something simple!

Thanks,
Allan

Answer (score 4):

Add this to `functions.php`

```
add_action('admin_init','my_meta_init');
function my_meta_init()
{
$post_id = $_GET['post'] ? $_GET['post'] : $_POST['post_ID'] ;
// checks for post/page ID
if ($post_id == '84')
{
    add_meta_box('my_all_meta_1', 'My Custom Meta Box 1', 'my_meta_setup_1', 'page', 'normal', 'high');
}
$template_file = get_post_meta($post_id,'_wp_page_template',TRUE);
// check for a template type
if ($template_file == 'home.php')
{
    add_meta_box('my_meta_2', 'My Custom Meta Box 2', 'my_meta_setup_2', 'page', 'normal', 'high');
}
```

It checks if edited page have proper id or using template. Choose one and change id, template name.

Comment: That conditional validation works with the **metabox plugin**, just put the `add_filter('rwmb_meta_boxes', 'function');` inside the conditional (if)

Comment: Your can also do this in functions.php **`$title_search = get_the_title($post_id);`** and make validations by title, and you wont be worried about changing the $post_id's number (if you have to migrate or the user deletes the page and create it again)